# groovy string comparsion in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Groovy version
$ groovy --version
Groovy Version: 2.4.7 JVM: 1.8.0_91 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Mac OS X

Following code works on my mac

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def StackStatusJson="aws  cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name XXXXXX".execute().text
println(StackStatusJson)
try{
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def object=jsonSlurper.parseText(StackStatusJson)

println("StackStatus->"+object.Stacks.StackStatus)

String v=object.Stacks.StackStatus

if(v.equals("[CREATE_COMPLETE]"))
{
    println("Calling Deploy Artifacts")
    deployArtifacts()
}
}catch(err)
{
    println(err);
}
def deployArtifacts()
{
    println "I am called"
}
```

But on a Jenkins v 2.15 pipeline the String comparison  below fails. I am not understanding why it is not making the condition true

```
if(v.equals("[CREATE_COMPLETE]"))
   {
    println("Calling Deploy Artifacts")
    deployArtifacts()
   }
}catch(err)
{
    println(err);
}
```

Sample JSON for testing is below values Stubbed

```
{
    "Stacks": [
        {
            "StackId": "XXXXX", 
            "Description": "XXXXXX Environment", 
            "Parameters": [
                {
                    "ParameterValue": "XXXXXXX", 
                    "ParameterKey": "proxy"
                }, 
                {
                    "ParameterValue": "XXXXXX", 
                    "ParameterKey": "amiid"
                }, 
                {
                    "ParameterValue": "XXXXXX", 
                    "ParameterKey": "TopicARN"
                }, 
                {
                    "ParameterValue": "XXXXXX", 
                    "ParameterKey": "yumproxy"
                }, 
                {
                    "ParameterValue": "m3.large", 
                    "ParameterKey": "InstanceType"
                }
            ], 
            "Tags": [], 
            "CreationTime": "2016-08-28T06:34:12.324Z", 
            "StackName": "XXXXXX", 
            "NotificationARNs": [], 
            "StackStatus": "CREATE_COMPLETE", 
            "DisableRollback": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this read `String v = object.Stacks[0].StackStatus` or does Groovy handle array access in a special way?

Comment: that did it thanks Stefan, if you post it as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code line

```
String v=object.Stacks.StackStatus
```

should read

```
String v = object.Stacks[0].StackStatus
```

since `object.Stacks` is an array.